# Creating a responsive website that changes color with CSS

Tags: css

Something similar to this

http://gomagames.com/blocks/blocks_sassy.html

How would this be achieved with css?

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include the code you have already tried, and an explanation of how it is not working.  Also, you may find this helpful: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @media rule in CSS.

This example change the background color of the body and the div tags depending of the screen size.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
    .mydiv {
      background-color:#000;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
    body {
        background-color: green;
    }
    .mydiv {
      background-color:#444;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1001px) {
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .mydiv {
      background-color:#999;
    }
}

.mydiv {
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  margin:10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
</div>
<div class="mydiv">
</div>
<div class="mydiv">
</div>
```